# seneca - communication between two microservices

Tags: microservices, seneca

I'm new in Seneca. I have been trying to make two microservices to communicate each other but I keep failing and get this errors:

> Error: Response Error: 404 Not Found
>       at module.exports.internals.Utils.internals.Utils.handle_response (c:\Users\Actiview\Desktop\microservices\orderManager\node_modules\seneca-transport\lib\transport-utils.js:71:11)
>       at c:\Users\Actiview\Desktop\microservices\orderManager\node_modules\seneca-transport\lib\http.js:154:25
>       at read (c:\Users\Actiview\Desktop\microservices\orderManager\node_modules\wreck\lib\index.js:590:24)
>       at finish (c:\Users\Actiview\Desktop\microservices\orderManager\node_modules\wreck\lib\index.js:398:20)
>       at wrapped (c:\Users\Actiview\Desktop\microservices\orderManager\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:879:20)
>       at module.exports.internals.Recorder.onReaderFinish (c:\Users\Actiview\Desktop\microservices\orderManager\node_modules\wreck\lib\index.js:449:16)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at module.exports.internals.Recorder.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:614:14)
>
> === SENECA FATAL ERROR === MESSAGE:  ::: seneca: Action  failed: Response Error: 404 Not Found. CODE:     ::: act_execute INSTANCE  :::
>   Seneca/pcbyi7v5c76v/1534346071465/6536/3.7.0/- DETAILS   ::: {
>   message: 'Response Error: 404 Not Found',
>                   pattern: '',
>                   fn: { [Function: transport_client] id: 'host:127.0.0.2,pg:,port:8080' },
>                   callback: 
>                    { [Function: bound action_reply]
>                      seneca: 
>                       Seneca {
>                         'private$': 
>                          { act: 
>                             { parent: 
>                                { start: 1534346071559,
>                                  end: 1534346071561, and more...

this is my code:

orderIndex.ts

```
    {
    const orderPlugin = require('./orderManagerPlugin');
    const  express = require('express');
    const SenecaWeb = require('seneca-web');
    const seneca = require("seneca")();
    let bodyParser = require('body-parser');



    var Routes = [{
        prefix: '/orders',
        pin: 'area:order,action:*',
        map: {
            fetch: { GET: true },
            create: { GET: false, POST: true },
            delete: { GET: false, DELETE: true },
        }
    }]

    var config = {
        routes: Routes,
        adapter: require('seneca-web-adapter-express'),
        context: express().use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' })).use(bodyParser.json()),
        options: {parseBody: false}
    }

    seneca.use(SenecaWeb,config);
    seneca.use(  orderPlugin  );


    seneca.ready(function (err) {
        const app = seneca.export('web/context')();
        app.listen({ host: "127.0.0.4", port: 8081 });
    });
    }
```

orderPlugin.ts

```
{
var plugin = function orderPlugin(options) {
    var seneca = this;
    var senecaEmailer;

    seneca.add({ area: "order", action: "fetch" }, function (args,
        done) {
        var orders = this.make("orders");
        orders.list$({ id: args.id }, done);
    });

    seneca.add({ area: "order", action: "delete" }, function (args,
        done) {
        var orders = this.make("orders");
        orders.remove$({ id: args.id }, function (err) {
            done(err, null);
        });
    });

    seneca.add({ area: "order", action: "create" }, function (args,
        done) {
        console.log('create order');
       senecaEmailer.act( 'role:web', {area: 'email', action:'send'}   , done);

    });

    this.add( { init: "orderPlugin" }, function (args, done) {  
        senecaEmailer = require("seneca")().client({ host: "127.0.0.2", port: 8080 });
        done();
    });
}

module.exports = plugin;
}
```

emailIndex.ts

```
{

const mailPlugin = require('./emailingPlugin');
const  express = require('express');
const SenecaWeb = require('seneca-web');
const seneca = require("seneca")();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var Routes = [{
    prefix: '/emails',
    pin: 'area:email, action:*',
    map: {
        send: { GET: true },
    }
}]

var config = {
    routes: Routes,
    adapter: require('seneca-web-adapter-express'),
    context: express().use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' })).use(bodyParser.json()),
    options: {parseBody: false}
}

seneca.use(SenecaWeb,config);
seneca.use(  mailPlugin  );


seneca.ready(function (err) {
    const app = seneca.export('web/context')();
    app.listen({ host: "127.0.0.2", port: 8080 } );
});
}
```

emailPlugin.ts

```
{

import {EmailService} from './emailService';
var plugin = function emailPlugin(options) {
    var seneca = this;
    let mailer :EmailService ;


    seneca.add({area: "email", action: "send"}, function(args, done) {
        mailer.sendMail('guzon56@gmail.com', done);
    });

    this.add( { init: "emailPlugin" }, function (args, done) {  
        console.log('before init');
        mailer = require('./emailService')();
        console.log('after init');
        done();
    });
};

   module.exports = plugin;
}
```

please help me.
Tnx.

Comment: Please, what is the ".ts" extension of your source files?

Answer (score 0):

Seneca is explained by Richard Rodger in [this post](http://www.richardrodger.com/seneca-microservices-nodejs#.W3aj8p9pFhE). The chapter "Service Discovery" talks about meshing the microservices in a network.

For my applications I use the [seneca-mesh](https://github.com/senecajs/seneca-mesh) plugin. This plugin README says:

> To join the network, all a service has to do is contact one other
>   service already in the network. The network then shares information
>   about which services respond to which patterns. There is no need to
>   configure the location of individual services anywhere.

Reading Richard's post and the plugin documentation could be a good starting point for your project. Hope it helps!